# Controller Test Failing Trying to Require Right User

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails 6 to work through the Hartl Tutorial, using mostly the online version. I'm in Chapter 10 (which doesn't correspond to the book version chapter numbering)...

https://www.railstutorial.org/book/updating_and_deleting_users

In Section 10.2.2, after Listing 10.25, the Rails Test should be green, but I get these 2 FAIL messages:

FAIL["test_should_redirect_edit_when_not_logged_in", #, 11.729448000027332]
 test_should_redirect_edit_when_not_logged_in#UsersControllerTest (11.73s)
        Expected true to be nil or false
        test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:18:in `block in '

FAIL["test_should_redirect_update_when_not_logged_in", #, 1.2034909999929368]
 test_should_redirect_update_when_not_logged_in#UsersControllerTest (1.20s)
        Expected true to be nil or false
        test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:26:in `block in '

The related code is this:

```
test "should redirect edit when not logged in" do
  log_in_as(@other_user)
  get edit_user_path(@user)
  assert_not flash.empty?
  assert_redirected_to login_url
end

test "should redirect update when not logged in" do
  log_in_as(@other_user)
  patch user_path(@user), params: { user: { name: @user.name,
                                            email: @user.email } }  
  assert_not flash.empty?
  assert_redirected_to login_url
end
```

It's the log_in_as(@other_user) that appears to be the problem, but it could be elsewhere. I can't see why this section has a problem when the similar one in users_edit_test.rb does not.

Comment: Two things I see: 

1. The book says the assertion should be: `assert_redirected_to root_url` while you are pointing at login_url. These could be different or the same depending on your app set up. 

2. Also it's not clear if you actually created other user. From your tests error message you are getting a failure rather than an error. So I don't think it's in the login. 

Try updating the expected urls and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for catching the URL difference. That isn't the problem though. I still get the same 2 Fail messages. I do have other_user created.

Comment: Try to inspect the response of the action call. Use something like byebug and inspect the `@response` variable that minitest creates or just put some `puts @response.inspect` after the call.

Comment: I added such an inspect and got a lot of output, but I can't see anything that's getting set to True that seems related to the problem. I was just keeping my head above water with this, but now I think I'm in over my head.

Comment: I found the problem. Not mentioned in the text was that "assert_not flash.empty?" should be changed to "assert flash.empty?"